# how to merge html table columns(or cells) based on their ids by using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, merge, cells

i am having the following html.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td> 
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='7'>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='7' >xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='8'>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='8'>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='8'>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='9' >xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='10' >xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='10'>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in this table i want to merge those cells whose id value is same.

for example:

in each row i am having 3 cells. and i am dynamically assigning the id value to the 3rd cell of each row. now i want to merge those cells whose id values are same with each other. like all  `td's` those are having id as  `"7"` i want to merge them as single cell. similarly for   `td's`having id value as   `"8"`and  `"9"` as one cell. like this so on. how can i do this by using the jQuery or java script?

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: so you want to use rowspan ?

Comment: i have taken unique ids only for the cells those i want to merge.

Comment: use class for defining the cells to be merged. Where do you want to merge the cells first cell with same class or last cell with same class or a specific cell with a specific class?

Comment: @ArunPJohny anything is fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xqfaqvck/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentID;
var count = 1;
var lastRow;
$("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).children(":eq(2)").attr("id");
    if (id === currentID) {
        count++;
        $(this).children(":eq(2)").remove();
    } else {
        $(lastRow).children(":eq(2)").attr("rowspan", count)
        currentID = id;
        count = 1;
        lastRow = this;
    }
});

if (count !== 1) {
    $(lastRow).children(":eq(2)").attr("rowspan", count);
}
```

```js
var currentID;
var count = 1;
var lastRow;
$("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
  var id = $(this).children(":eq(2)").attr("id");
  if (id === currentID) {
    count++;
    $(this).children(":eq(2)").remove();
  } else {
    $(lastRow).children(":eq(2)").attr("rowspan", count)
    currentID = id;
    count = 1;
    lastRow = this;
  }
});

if (count !== 1) {
  $(lastRow).children(":eq(2)").attr("rowspan", count);
}
```

```css
td {
    border: solid 1px black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='7'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='7'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='8'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='8'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='8'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='9'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='10'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td id='10'>xyz</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Solution approach:-
```

You have to alter the logic in such a way that whenever similar id comes, for instance, id="7" in the first record then put a rowspan attribute and count the number of time it comes. Accordingly you can put the rowspan number n there then remove the  where ever that id has occurred from below. I assume that these id are assigned continuously not random

```
<tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id='8' rowspan="N">>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
     </tr>

    <table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wh5Lx1f0/
I agree with other guys that ids must be unique.

```
var idToElementCount = {};
$('[data-id]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('data-id');
    if(!idToElementCount.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        idToElementCount[id] = 0;
    }

    idToElementCount[id]++;
});

for(var currentId in idToElementCount) {
    $('[data-id='+currentId + "]")
        .first()
        .attr("rowspan", idToElementCount[currentId])
        .end()
    .filter(":gt(0)")
    .remove()



}
```